# How to import python module from docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I made a docker image contains nginx, uwsgi and some python module, using volumes out the docker to develop code.

So how should I use python environment from docker when coding?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in more details!

Comment: You want to coding inside docker container ?

Comment: @pigletfly no, I want to coding outside docker but import some module inside docker.

Comment: see new edit. I think this general direction in which this problem could be solved.

Comment: @Mil0R3 , hi, did you manage to import a module in a docker container to outside code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But here are some tips, that may help you.

1. Python libraries for working with docker from python

   - https://github.com/docker/docker-py
   - https://github.com/deepgram/sidomo
2. You can start container's python console
   `docker run -ti myimage python`
3. Also you can have connected `volumes` where you will store your source code and than run this code with container's environment

**NEW IDEA**

Importing module in python means having module's folder in your `PYTHONPATH`. So basically you probably would need to mount your docker with something like [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) to some folder, and than add this folder to your `PYTHONPATH`. After that you can do `from {docker_module} ...`

Comment: I have done this, what' my problem: for example django module is inside docker now, outside the docker (volumes) I can write code, when I type `from django.`, how can I get code hints?

Comment: @Milor8 why would you want that? I don't understand reasoning for this.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I think I know what he means as I'm facing a similar issue with [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html). As the installation procedure for its python wrapper on systems other than Ubuntu is somewhat not straightforward, I thought about using a [ubuntu docker container with a caffe python module installation](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docker/cpu/Dockerfile). My question, and maybe OPs question, is how can I import a python module that was installed in a container?

Comment: @fabda01, hi, did you manage to import a module in a docker container to outside code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking but if you have Python libraries within the Docker image and you want to append them to an already-exisitng `Pipfile`, you can copy the `requirements.txt` file from the Docker container and then use `pipenv` to install them.

```sh
# In terminal session 1 run the container with the default shell in interactive mode. This way the container stays alive and we can copy the file from the container to the host
docker run -it --rm $USER/$IMAGE_NAME:1.0.0.XXXXX sh

# In terminal session 2
docker cp $CONTAINER_ID:/requirements.txt ./

# This will add the requirements from the text file into the Pipfile
pipenv install -r requirement.txt

# Sometimes requirements will get corrupted
pipenv clean
```

If using Visual Studio Code, reload window to refresh dependencies in Python interpreter.